# How can I safely debug my Django Website hosted on apache2 server?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, debugging, web-deployment

I am trying to change my website which is hosted on a Linux machine with Ubuntu. I am able to access it using **ssh username@serverIPadress** command on my local machine.

Now, when I change my code I get a 500 server error message, so I can't check where I am doing something wrong.

Do I have to change **Debug = True** in my settings.py file and what do I need to fill in at **ALLOWED HOSTS**? Currently, I have ALLOWED HOSTS = {domainname, server IP}.

So, is there a **secure way** to change my deployed Django Website locally on my own machine?

Maybe, I am changing it too complicated, but I am not a webdeveloper. I can't get an answer when I read the documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use debug_toolbar by adding it in setting.py installed app and adding allowed ip at the end

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ['your ip']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. I also came across [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#admins]